# Classifying vectors that only contains 1001110101 numbers - Is Support Vector Machine the solution?

Tags: binary, classification, svm, sparse-matrices

Assume that you are given a vector `0b1101001001011001` etc. And you are going to classify it.
One can use Support Vector Machine, but is that method good for classifying data that are spare and binary?

Assume that you are given a real vector $x$ with dimension $N$. The vector contains only ones and zeros. $x = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]^T$

You are not given one vector $x$, instead you are given a matrix of vectors e.g $X = [x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots , x_M]$ where $N$ is constant but $M$ can vary.

From the matrix $X$, you are also given a vector called labels $y$. The labels are labled either with -1 or +1. The labels $y$ is one vector with the same length as $M$.

So, from the labels $y$ and matrix $X$, you can find weights $W$ and bias $b$ on the form

$$y_i = Wx_i^T + b$$

But is SVM a good way to classify this type data?

Comment: You need much more information than this to answer the question.

Comment: @PålGD done....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the features in your case are exclusively categorical. Support Vector Machines might work, but they would not be my model of choice for such data. SVMs try to separate the classes by a plane¹ with maximum distance to the closest samples in (transformed) feature space. That distance, however, is pointless with categorical data.

I would suggest that You try [Decision Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) which give well-interpretable  results. If Decision Trees are not working for you, give [Random Decision Forests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) a try.

¹ In some high-dimensional kernel space.

Comment: Thank you. Hmmm....decision tress might be unstable.